# CKEditor SetData() only works first time. What am I missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Basically I have a table of 'notes' and when you click on one it opens up in a modal. I wanted to change my `textarea` into a `ckeditor` instance and use that but I am having an issue where the first note clicks loads fine but after that will load the content of the first one that was clicked.

Lets say I have note 'a' and note 'b'.

If I open note 'a' and see the contents say "hello I am note a" then I close this note and open note 'b' it will still say "hello I am note a" still instead of the proper content.

Here is my current code.

In the document ready function at top

```
var noteEditor = CKEDITOR.replace("noteDetailEdit", {
    baseHref: CKEDITOR.basePath,
    customConfig: CTX_PATH + '/resources/js/ckeditor_config.js'
});
```

here is the `displayNote()` function that is called when the note link is clicked.

```
function displaynote(id) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.noteDetailEdit.setData( $("#detail-" + id).val());

    var title = $("#title-" + id).val();
    var active = $("#active-" + id).val();
    var version = $("#version-" + id).val();
    $("#noteTitle_readonly").val(title);
    $("#noteId_readonly").val(noteId);
    $("#active_readonly").val(active);
    $("#version_readonly").val(version);
    modal("#notes_modal_readonly");
}
```

So I guess why I am confused is why it works the first time you click but not the other times.

The `textarea` starts out empty and when the link is clicked and `displayNote()` is called it and correctly sets the data.

So why is it not setting the data again and displaying it correctly?

### Edit

How display note is called.

you will see the call to the displayNote() js function below.

```
<c:if test="${!empty programDto.programNote}">
                <c:forEach items="${programDto.programNote}" var="programNote">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" data-id="${programNote.id}" /></td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <c:out value="${programNote.noteTitle}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript:displaynote('${programNote.id}')">
                                <c:set var="detail" value="${programNote.noteDetail}" />
                                <c:if test="${fn:length(detail) > 45}">
                                    <c:set var="detail" value="${fn:substring(detail, 0, 45)}..." />
                                </c:if>
                                <c:out value="${detail}" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <joda:format value="${programNote.lastModifiedDate}" var="parsedNoteDate" pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy" />
                            <c:out value="${parsedNoteDate}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
```

Comment: Can you show in code exactly how `dipslayNote()` is called?

Comment: Please make sure that `id` which you pass to `displaynote()` is different for each note.

Comment: j.swiderski   - I did confirm this by printing the id out in the console and it is correct.   Also i have added a note above about how displayNote() is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

I did SetData as a callback function inside the function that displays the modal.